# App Bar extendida

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

¿Cómo puedo implementar una app bar extendida, igual que la que aparece en la imagen?

[image: Extended app bar]

Comment: Te refieres a un collasingToolbar ?

Comment: Si te refieres únicamente a la barra, usa un Toolbar y define una altura, trata lo que comento en mi respuesta y comenta si obtuviste lo deseado.

Comment: Sí, quería crear un Collapsing Toolbar  que estuviese detrás del recyclerView y que cuando se haga scroll el Collapsing Toolbar desapareciese y apareciese.

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar una barra personalizada la mejor opción actualmente es usar un [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) y para realizar lo que deseas puedes definir la propiedad `android:minHeight` con el valor `?attr/actionBarSize` para tener como altura mínima la de la barra de acción:

```
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

y definir una altura fija mediante:

```
android:layout_height="128dp"
```

Ejemplo:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Agrego un ejemplo de nuestros amigos de "hermosa programación":
**[Toolbar en Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/06/toolbar-en-android-creacion-de-action-bar-en-material-design/)**

Comment: simple y practico !